# C# Track copied files

Tags: c#, windows, copy, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to keep track of files that are copied by users and other applications.
The FileSystemWatch only has events for Changed, Created, Deleted, Disposed, Error, and Renamed.
It doesn't fire an event when a file is accessed by the copy function or where the new file is being copied to.

Is there a method for monitoring the copy event/function of windows?

Comment: Can you watch at the clipboard instance instead? Just a thought.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx

Comment: How well can you tolerate failure to track a copy? You can probably track _most_ copies (e.g. those done through Explorer), but some will slip through.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way using C#.

You can do this if you are willing to write a [File System Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx). [Definitely expert territory, as there is scope for corrupting files and/or bringing down your system]

> A file system filter driver intercepts requests targeted at a file
>   system or another file system filter driver. By intercepting the
>   request before it reaches its intended target, the filter driver can
>   extend or replace functionality provided by the original target of the
>   request. Examples of file system filter drivers include anti-virus
>   filters, backup agents, and encryption products. To develop file
>   systems and file system filter drivers, use the IFS (Installable File
>   System) Kit, which is provided with the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

Comment: Filter driver can track separate read and write operations but it can not establish the link between two. It's not possible to identify copying in a definite way.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right thing with `FileSystemWatcher`. Windows does not have any built-in mechanism for reporting copies reliably.

You could hook the OS copy routine, but this won't guarantee you good results: applications are free to implement their own copy by just opening the source and destination files and copying the bytes over.

Renaming is different because a rename done by the OS cannot be easily mimicked through other means, so you will catch all renames with the `FileSystemWatcher`. Note that moving between drives is more like copy: you won't get a Renamed notification, but a Created and a Deleted instead.

So if you really really need to notice a file getting copied, my suggested approach is this:

- [Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx) the `CloseFile` calls, in addition to the `FileSystemWatcher`.
- Whenever a file gets closed, it could be because it's the source or target of a copy / cross-drive move. Check its size.
- If you find two closed files with the same size within a reasonably short period of time, compare the content. Pretty resource-intensive, but the only reliable way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Auditing file and folder access](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_evmonevents_17.mspx?mfr=true) feature of Windows which writes an event log entry and you can setup programs to start when such an event occurs

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any good way.

For each newly created file, you need to check if there is an exact duplicate (perhaps with a different name) anywhere on the filesystem. You could obviously do this brute-force, but the solution would be very inelegant, slow and brittle!